# Pasar de hash a password_hash en sql

Tags: php, sql

estoy teniendo problemas, a la hora de hacer y pasar las pass de hash a password_hash() para hacer la validación mediante password_verify();

El caso es que he cambiado la versión php a la última, y no se pueden loguear. Su registro ha sido con hash('sha512') y ahora he puesto que valide la password con password_verify, pero no lo valida, entonces quiero hacer una sentencia en la base de datos para pasar esas passwords a password_hash() como tendría que hacer?

Comment: Si no he entendido mal, lo que planteas no se puede hacer. Ya que para hacer el _hash_ necesitar el _password_ original. Lo que si se puede hacer y es recomendable es implementar la función [_password_needs_rehash_](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-needs-rehash.php) precisamente para conocer si cuando cambias de entorno, cambia la configuración para generar las mismas. Dicho esto, lo que te recomiendo es que en el nuevo entorno, solicitar que cada uno resetee su contraseña, la cual al crearse con la nueva configuración se creará correctamente.

Comment: Desgraciadamente no existe forma de rehashear las claves de forma directa. Lo adecuado en estos casos es que en el login implemente una doble comprobación similar una implementación de `password_needs_rehash`,  1° válidas password con el método antiguo, si es válido rehashear con `password_hash()` la password introducida por el usuario y actualizas el registro en bd. Si la validación  con el método antiguo no es válido,  compruebas con `password_verify` y decides si pasa o no. Quizás si nos proporcionas un ejemplo de tu implementación podamos darte un ejemplo orientativo. Un saludo.